# Pagination table

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape a table for each page and then bring them all together into a dataframe. The code below works for pages 0 to 5:

```
pages <- 0:5
urls <- paste0("http://www.expansionyempleo.com/buscar-trabajo-empleo/cid/3BC18A08D9BB661C9B65C93203B654EF/canal/0/pagenumber/",pages)

get_table <- function(url) {
url %>%
read_html() %>%
html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mytable"]') %>% 
html_table()
}

results <- sapply(urls, get_table)
results <- rbind_all(results)
View(results)
```

However, when I increase the pages from 5 to for example 20 I get the following error:

Error in bind_rows_(x, id = id) : Argument 1 must have names

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following code without getting an error using loops instead of apply:

```
pages <- 0:5
urls <- paste0("http://www.expansionyempleo.com/buscar-trabajo-empleo/cid/3BC18A08D9BB661C9B65C93203B654EF/canal/0/pagenumber/",pages)
result <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(urls)) {

   temp_result <- read_html(urls[i]) %>%
   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mytable"]') %>% 
   html_table() %>%
   as.data.frame()

   result <- rbind(result, temp_result)
}
```

However, I think the structure of the page changes or avoids displaying more than 5 pages without registration?! (I lack of Spanish knowledge here).
However, if you try to open the url with page > 5, the following popup is shown:

> Para poder seguir revisando las vacantes de empleo en nuestro sitio,
>   debes ingresar con tu E-mail y Contraseña

So what you encounter seems to be rather a page view restriction than a coding issue.

Your code is quite cool btw (have always worked in loops for that kind of issues) and does not seem to be the reason for the error message.